# Deduce $ \forall x P(x) \vdash \exists xP(x) $

Tags: predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

Well it's a little awkward but how can I show this in a natural deduction proof?

$ \forall x P(x) \vdash \exists xP(x) $

I think one has too proof that with a *proof by contradiction rule* but since I cannot eliminate the $ \exists $ quantifier I am stuck. I know this is a quite simple example.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The empty model doesn't satisfy the corresponding implication.

Comment: I don't think you can: the condition $\;\forall\,x\;P(x)\;$ could be fulfilled in an empty way, whereas $\;\exists\,x\;P(x)\;$ determines there's at least one such case.

Comment: This depends on your rules, but it should go something like the following. Take an arbitrary constant $a$ (assuming the universe is not empty, of course), eliminate $\forall$ with $a$ to get $P(a)$, now introduce $\exists$ to get $\exists xP(x)$.

Comment: @GitGud But without any further assumptions "*like the universe $P$ is not empty*" **Timbuc** and **Berci** are right, right?

Comment: @StefanFalk Yes, but the universe having at least an object is something that's most likely stated in the first page of the text book, notes, whatever. Something like "from now on there is always at least one constant".

Comment: @StefanFalk The usual systems of natural deduction do not speculate about the size of the universe but instead boldly introduce rules of inference, among those are the ones used by GitGud. A theory where any statement beginning with $\forall x$ is true and with $\exists x$ is false, is boring anyway. - If you work with a text book, look through the quantor specific rules of inference listed there.

Comment: Alright I think I got it. Thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a consequence of the rule of Universal Specification in standard first-order logic (FOL). Implicit is the assumption that the domain of discourse is non-empty.

In my own work,  I never make use of this assumption. I usually make the domain of discourse explicit, e.g $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}: P(x)$ We know that $\exists x\in\mathbb{R}$, so we can infer that $\exists x\in\mathbb{R}:P(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

For a proof with *natural Deduction*, we refer to Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1447145577) (5th ed - 2013) for the rules :

> $$\frac{∀x \varphi(x) }{\varphi(t)} \text {∀E ; we require $t$ to be free for $x$ in $\varphi$  [page 86] }$$
>
> $$\frac{\varphi[t/x] }{∃x \varphi} \text {∃I, with $t$ free for $x$ in $\varphi$ [page 93]}$$

---

The proof is quite simple :

*(i)* $∀xP(x)$ --- assumed

*(ii)* $P(z)$ --- from (i) by $∀E$, where $z$ is a *variable* not used in $P(x)$

*(iii)* $∃xP(x)$ --- from (ii) by $∃I$

> > $∀xP(x) ⊢ ∃xP(x)$

---

The above proof is consistent with the previous comments; see van Dalen [page 54] :

> **Definition 3.2.1** A *structure* is an ordered sequence $\langle A, R_1,\ldots, R_n, F_1,\ldots, F_m, \{ c_i |i \in I \} \rangle$, where $A$ is a *non-empty* [emphasis added] set. $R_1,\ldots, R_n$ are relations on $A$, $F_1,\ldots, F_m$ are functions on $A$, and the $c_i (i \in I)$ are elements of $A$ (constants).

---

In order to admit also empty domains, the above rules regarding quantifiers must be modified; see [Free Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/).