# Is possibile to prove the double implication $\Big(¬\big((∀x)P(x)\big)\Big)\iff\Big((∃x)\big(¬P(x)\big)\Big)$ using classical logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

**THIS QUESTION IS NOT A DUPLICATE OF THESE ONES!!!**

- [$\exists x. P(x)
  \to\lnot \forall x. \lnot P(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3879908/how-do-i-prove-the-equivalence-of-exists-x-px-and-lnot-forall-x-lnot)
- [$\neg \forall x P(x) \leftrightarrow \exists x \neg P(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4137847/prove-that-neg-forall-x-px-leftrightarrow-exists-x-neg-px)
- [$\forall x P(x) \vdash \exists xP(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976960/deduce-forall-x-px-vdash-exists-xpx)
- [$\lnot\exists xP(x)\rightarrow\forall x\lnot P(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300925/prove-by-natural-deduction-that-lnot-exists-xpx-rightarrow-forall-x-lnot-px)
- [$\forall x\neg P(x) ⊢\neg \exists xP(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482971/predicate-logic-proof-forall-x-neg-px-%e2%8a%a2-neg-exists-xpx)

So on the [first chapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbas7.jpg) of the text *Set theory for the mathematician* by Jean E. Rubin there is a brief summary of mathematical logic and there it is stated that the double implications
$$
\Big(\big(\neg(\exists x)\big)P(x)\Big)\iff\Big((\forall x)\big(\neg(P(x)\big)\Big)
$$
and
$$
\Big(\neg\big((\forall x)P(x)\big)\Big)\iff\Big((\exists x)\big(\neg(P(x)\big)\Big)
$$
are tautology but this is not proved so that I thought to ask a question where I ask how prove them using propositional calculus. Actually [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3880016/736008) I found a possibile answer but unfortunately I did not understood: indeed, although I perfectly know Law of Excluded Middle (LEM) and although I know I can do some "algebraic" manipulation with symbol $\neg$, $\wedge$ and $\vee$ I did not understand the linked proof; moreover, even [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1673147/736008) I found a possibile answer but (I do not really why) I feel like it is not rigorous. Finally, I admit it is not completely clear the meaning of universal quantifier by Rudin arguments: indeed, I surely can realize that the sentence $(\exists x)\big(P(x)\big)$ "exists any $x$ with respect $P$ is true" is a primitive so that I would define $(\forall x)\big(P(x)\big)$ true whether $\exists x\to P(x)$ is a tautology but I do not really know if this is rigorous.

Anyway I understanding the proof can require some particular notions in Mathematical Logic so that I even ask a textbook where I can study into 50-100 pages the most important results to apply rigorously the more common and "natural" logical arguments: it seems to me that into the first two chapter of [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1482237725) textbook there is what I looking for but I am not sure it actually presents the subject rigorously.

So could someone help me, please?

**N.B:**

Obviously if you believe that by Rudin's rudiments I can actually understand any answer I linked above you can try to explain it here better so that I can understand it.

Comment: Since $\exists$ and $\forall$ are not part of propositional calculus, it seems unlikely. This is only true if these symbols have their usual relationship.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Okay, so how Rudin's prove the double implication? Could you indicate me a text where I can found the proof reading 50-100 pages?

Comment: The proof depends on the rules used. The proof linked in your second line above is fine.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Okay, so is the second line [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4137847/prove-that-neg-forall-x-px-leftrightarrow-exists-x-neg-px), right? is it valid with respect Rudin's formalism?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Could I ask why the symbol $\leftrightarrow$ I used was not good? Pheraps if i wanted use it then I would have to ask to prove that the poposition $\Big(¬\big((∀x)P(x)\big)\Big)\leftrightarrow\Big((∃x)\big(¬P(x)\big)\Big)$ is a tautology?

Comment: It is good. It means bi-conditional and in classical logic both conditionals (left to right and right to left) hold.

Comment: Presumably, Rudin uses first order logic rather than propositional calculus. Or perhaps he gives an informal argument meant to give you the reasoning the thing would be true.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Okay: could I ask you a text where I can study some first-order logic? do you know [Mendelson](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1482237725) text? is it good?

Comment: If you click on the links to bullet points 1 and 4, you’ll pretty much have your answer. Just know that $(\phi \to \psi) \land (\neg \phi \to \neg \psi)$ is equivalent to $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$ in Classical Logic.

Comment: @PW_246 I presume you want means that by the first and fourth link I can argue the result since I know the proposition $\big((\phi\to\psi)\wedge(\neg\phi\to\neg\psi)\big)\leftrightarrow(\phi\leftrightarrow\psi)$  is a tautology , right? However if you want means this I said into the answer I did not understand proof of linked questions.

Comment: Arguably already asked and answered: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673135/prove-that-forall-x-neg-px-iff-neg-exists-x-px/1673147#1673147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every example you provided is either not a formal proof or not a proof using propositional logic (PL) alone. You could certainly construct an informal, intuitive explanation for why these equivalencies hold true, but a *formal* proof of the equivalencies

$\neg \exists x P(x) \leftrightarrow \forall x \neg P(x)$ and
$\neg \forall x P(x) \leftrightarrow \exists x \neg P(x)$

requires first-order logic (FOL). This is because the equivalencies depend on the internal grammatical structure of the formulas involved, and PL does not possess the necessary machinery for abstracting the internal grammatical structure of formulas. PL is only useful for representing an argument whose validity depends on the relative arrangement of the formulas involved.

On the other hand, FOL does possess the necessary machinery for representing the internal grammatical structure of formulas, particularly those asserting one of the following: $(1)$ that all, none, or some elements of a given domain possess (or do not possess) certain properties, or $(2)$ that all, none, or some elements of a given domain bear (or do not bear) some relation to  all, none, or some elements of the domain. Those branches of FOL dealing with $(1)$ and $(2)$ are known as monadic FOL and polyadic FOL, respectively.

That is not to say that some arguments in the language of FOL cannot be proven using PL alone. Indeed, some arguments in FOL can be proven in PL alone. However, the validity of such arguments must depend on the relative arrangement of the formulas involved and *not* the internal grammatical structure of the formulas. For instance, a proof of $\forall x Px \to \exists x Qx, \forall x Px \vdash  \exists x Qx$ requires nothing more than Modus Ponens, an inference rule of PL. Proving an argument in a "higher-level" formal system, such as FOL, using only the inference rules of a "lower-level" system, such as PL, is referred to as *shallow analysis.*

In order to understand or construct a formal proof of the equivalencies you provided, you need to learn PL and monadic FOL at a minimum. FOL is a generalization of PL that $(a)$ inherits all inference rules of PL and $(b)$ defines a few more inference rules, namely, elimination and introduction rules for the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$. Polyadic FOL deals with relational predicates and requires two more inference rules, that is, identity introduction and identity elimination, but polyadic FOL is not necessary for proofs of the above equivalencies. Any textbook covering PL and FOL will give you the necessary background. I recommend [A Concise Introduction to Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1305958098) by Hurley ($13$th ed).